# Using MVVM Communitytoolkit to change property of initialed list of buttons using RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, relaycommand, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have WPF application with .NETCore 7 and when it load I have view and viewmodel

I generate a list of buttons using code in viewmodel as following

```
 public partial class DataViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigationAware
    {
        private bool _isInitialized = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Scene> _scenes;


        public void OnNavigatedTo()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                InitializeViewModel();
        }

        public void OnNavigatedFrom()
        {
        }

        private void InitializeViewModel()
        {
            var scenesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Scene>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                string name = "Scene " + (i + 1);
                var scene = new Scene
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 231, 129, 4)),
                    Icon = SymbolRegular.Play48,
                    IsPlaying = false
                };
                scene.PlayStopCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PlayStop(scene));
                scenesCollection.Add(scene);
            }

            Scenes = scenesCollection;

            _isInitialized = true;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void PlayStop(Scene scene)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            if (scene.IsPlaying)
            {
                scene.Icon = SymbolRegular.Play48;
                scene.IsPlaying = false;
            }
            else
            {
                scene.Icon = SymbolRegular.Pause48; // Change the icon to the desired value
                scene.IsPlaying = true;
            }
            scene.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(
                (byte)200,
                (byte)random.Next(0, 250),
                (byte)random.Next(0, 250),
                (byte)random.Next(0, 250)));
        }
    }
```

Structure for scene are as followed

```
 public struct Scene
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Brush Color { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand PlayStopCommand { get; set; }

        public SymbolRegular Icon { get; set; }

        public bool IsPlaying { get; set; }
    }
```

XMAL code

```
<ui:VirtualizingItemsControl
            Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorSecondaryBrush}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Scenes, Mode=OneWay}"
            VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Scene}">
                    <ui:Button
                        x:Name="buttin"
                        Width="600"
                        Height="50"
                        Margin="2"
                        Padding="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Appearance="Secondary"
                        Background="{Binding Color, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Command="{Binding PlayStopCommand}"
                        Content="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        FontSize="25"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Icon="{Binding Icon, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IconFilled="True" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ui:VirtualizingItemsControl>
```

The buttons do initialize correctly, however, when I click on any buttons nothing changes.

I even tried to use Breakpoints and I found out that every time I call the PlayStopCommand scene.IsPlaying is always false and does not change, so this means that the code somehow changes another temporary scene, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the Scene structure to ObservableObject

```
   public partial class Scene : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public int _iD;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string? name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public Brush? color;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public RelayCommand? playStopCommand;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public SymbolRegular icon;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool isPlaying;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the mechanism you use to identify the button/scene that has been clicked:

In `scene.PlayStopCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PlayStop(scene));` you have a closure for the local `scene` variable.
This means that when the command is executed, the actual value (at that moment in time) for `scene` is used. But at that moment `scene` does no longer exist: it was locally scoped to the for-loop iteration.

So you need to find another way to find the exact button that was clicked.
There is an easy way to do this. e.g.:

1. refactor your command to accept a string-parameter:

   `public RelayCommand<string> PlayStopCommand { get; set; }`
2. pass the `Name` property of the scene as a CommandParameter:

   ```
    Command="{Binding PlayStopCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Name"
   ```
3. refactor the command implementation to accept the name as parameter (and identify the clicked button from that):

   ```
   scene.PlayStopCommand = new RelayCommand((name) => PlayStop(name));
   ```

with the adapted `PlayStop`method:

```
   public void PlayStop(string name)
   {
      // find the right scene in the _scenes collection
      var scene = _scenes.First((s) => s.Name == name); 
      
      var random = new Random();
      if (scene.IsPlaying)
      ...
```

Finally: if you want any changes in the scene properties to be reflected in your UI, you need to notify the view of the change (your _scenes' collection is observable, but the properties of a scene are not in the code you posted).

Edit: that last part is dealt with in your own answer...